# Unicode MySQL data creating encoding error in XML

Tags: mysql, ajax, xml, encoding, utf

I have a column in MySQL that contains a wide variety of characters from many different languages and scripts, and I saw elsewhere that `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` was a good all-purpose encoding for this type of data, so I have that set as the collation for that column.

When I use the data to create an AJAX response in XML, however, I'm getting an encoding error regardless of what I set the XML header to. I have tried setting the XML encoding thus:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf8mb4_unicode_ci"?>
```

But I then get an `Unsupported encoding` error. I'll admit to being a bit mystified by how encoding works, and dealing with it in multiple languages makes it worse. Is there a way to specify this encoding for XML, a way to translate from `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` to something XML understands, or should I use a different collation setting in the MySQL database?

**EDIT:** Maybe I'm making a mistake unrelated to encoding? Here is what I have. Given this MySQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE composer (name VARCHAR(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci);
INSERT INTO composer (name) VALUES('Béla Bartók'),('Antonín Dvořák');
```

...and this PHP file:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new $mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database);
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
print("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><root>");
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM composer");
$res->data_seek(0);
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    print("<name>" . $row['name'] . "</name>");
}
print("</root>");
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Opening this result in my browser gives an encoding error, and peeking at the resulting the web inspector window shows placeholder characters in place of the accented characters. Is this just because of the tool (Safari) I'm using to peek at the XML file? Should I just sally forth into parsing the XML response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`utf8mb4_unicode_ci` is what MySQL calls UTF-8 for the full 4-byte range.
So in your xml just specify  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Also try using `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");` after connection to set the connection charset to utf8

Comment: I tried that and still get the encoding error, so I must be missing something else. I've added some sample code to my question (though the the MySQL dependency prevents me from giving you a JSFiddle). I appreciate any other insight you might have.

Comment: Is the data correct in the database? Can you check with phpmyadmin or something?

Comment: Yes, phpMyAdmin is showing the data with the correct characters.

Comment: Try using `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")` after connection to set the connection charset to utf8

Comment: Success! You're a saint, Musa. Thank you so much!